# How to implement horizontal scroll view for the whole page in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Need to implement horizontal scroll view UI exactly same as the attached two images. I need the selected view to be at center and magnified while the remaining two of the view edges must be shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into using a UIPageViewController contained in a view near the bottom of your main ViewController?

Comment: yes I can. but the problem is I can't able have those small black box views containing  screen number  where the selected screen is at the center magnified and other ones edges must be shown. This is where am stuck

Comment: I suspect you mean "2nd Screen" in the second screenshot? Also, I suspect this question is really too broad for SO. You're going to need to work a little harder to show what you've tried.

Comment: @brandonscript yes I just need to implement the bottom horizontal view where edges of first and third are shown. and one at the center is magnified. I just need to implement this along with whole background transition